# How can I consume a WCF service using a local WSDL file?

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

I need to consume a WCF service based on a (preferably single) wsdl file.

The environment is VS-2008 (sp1), and I will be using a customized "Add Service Reference" macro to generate an error handling proxy. I want to be able to do this, by supplying a WSDL file that I get from the service provider (I do not want to supply a host URL).

How can this be done?

Answer (score 19):

Sure - you can copy the path+filename for the WSDL and paste that into the "Add Service Reference" dialog box in Visual Studio (or just type int the full path + WSDL file name).

[image]

Alternatively, you can use the `svcutil.exe` command line utility to convert the WSDL file to your client proxy class.

Comment: I tried adding a service reference from a local wsdl, one that has multiple contracts, and all I got was a blank reference.cs file (it had the code-gen remarks, but that's it).

Any idea why?

Thanks,
Assaf.

Comment: that would indicate an invalid WSDL, probably - or it can't handle the multiple services inside the same WSDL - not 100% sure

Comment: Geez!  Why can't Microsoft add an open file dialog?  At the very least lanel the field "Address or file path:"

Comment: @ATL_DEV, Microsoft have added the open-file dialog to .Net core.