# How to add service reference from customer's private network

Tags: c#, web-services

I need to develop a `service client application` in `C#`. The service is hosted on customer's local network which I have no access. So I cannot use `Add Service Reference` option to create service proxy. 
The customer gave me only the XML Soap declarations of their service. It looks like the following:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <!--  Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Oracle JAX-WS 2.1.5. 
  --> 
- <!--  Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Oracle JAX-WS 2.1.5. 
  --> 
- <definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://helios.tedas.gov.tr/im" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://helios.tedas.gov.tr/im" name="IletisimModulu">
- <types>
```

It is just the head of XML, I am not putting the full XML because of its size. I think this is what we would see if we navigate to service url from explorer (`http://mywebservice/Service?WSDL`).

So now, how can I create service proxy from this XML document that they gave me?

Comment: [WSDL.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6(v=vs.80).aspx): "The Web Services Description Language tool generates code for XML Web services and XML Web service clients from WSDL contract files, XSD schemas, and .discomap discovery documents."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I cannot use Add Service Reference option to create service proxy.

You can paste a file path there as well as an URL. See also [How can I consume a WCF service using a local WSDL file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483178/how-can-i-consume-a-wcf-service-using-a-local-wsdl-file).